# Resolve dynamic path in wireMock

Tags: java, spring, wiremock

Hi there I've relativley new to the Wiremock framework. I've got a test enviroment working but I need to for our integration testing need to resolve a dynamic path such as

/test/dynamic/{dynamicpath}/help

where dynamic path is going to be a variable that I want to resolve and then present different data from using a subset of a json file such as

{
  dynamicpathA : "hello",
  dynamicpathB "world"
}

at the moment I have :

```
    stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/test/dynamic/{dynamicpath}/help"))
            .withHeader("accept", equalTo("application/json"))
            .willReturn(aResponse().withBody(readFile(RESOURCES + "test.json", Charset.defaultCharset()))));
```

which will return an entire json file with the full subset of data but not the individual components in relation to the dynamic uri. My question is there a way to resolve the dynamic url and return dynamic data from the json?

I hope I'm being specific enough I'll update as need be.

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible. What you want is a [Response Transformer](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#response-definition-transformation).

You have done the right thing with the path regex matcher which will identify a positive match - that is the end of it's involvement though, the rest is up to the Response Transformer.

You have a couple of options for parsing out the `dynamicPath` part with Response Transformers, you can either a) supply it as a parameter to the transformer or b) let the Response Transformer evaluate the request URL for the path. Here is an example letting the Response Transformer do all the work.

```
public static class DynamicTransformer extends ResponseDefinitionTransformer {

    @Override
    public ResponseDefinition transform(Request request, ResponseDefinition responseDefinition, FileSource files, Parameters parameters) {
          String path = request.getUrl();
          String dynamicPath = ...;     // Pull out the dynamic part
          String transformedJson = ...; // Render the JSON string applicable 
          return new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody(transformedJson)
                .build();
    } 

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "dynamic-transformer";
    }
```

So then your test looks like

```
WireMockServer wireMock = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig()
     .extensions(new DynamicTransformer()));

stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/test/dynamic/[^/]+/help"))
    .withHeader("accept", equalTo("application/json"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
    .withTransformers("dynamic-transformer")));
```